# Why are `const` pointers to functions not usable in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr, constant-expression

Consider the following template:

```
using IntFnPtr = int(*)(int);
template <IntFnPtr> void f() { }
```

And these tests:

```
int g(int) { }

int main()
{
    f<&g>(); // OK

    const IntFnPtr cp = &g;
    f<cp>(); // Error -- why? 

    constexpr IntFnPtr cexprp = &g;
    f<cexprp>(); // OK
}
```

**Why is the attempt to instantiate `f` with `cp` ill-formed?** The compiler complains about:

```
> error: no matching function for call to 'f'
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aszn4P)

---

Note that this seems inconsistent with other entities, such as integers:

```
template <int> void f() { }

int main()
{
    f<5>(); // OK

    const int ci = 5;
    f<ci>(); // OK

    constexpr int cexpri = 5;
    f<cexpri>(); // OK
}
```

Comment: "this seems inconsistent with other entities, such as integers" is backwards.  Integers are inconsistent with everything else.

Comment: I don't know what you are abbreviating as NTTP.

Comment: @BenVoigt non-type-template-parameter. But disregard that, it only seems to work for completely empty types.

Comment: Actually, clang gives a decently helpful diagnostic in this case: "`f<cp>()` doesn't work because it's not the address of a function with external linkage". gcc says nothing at all :(

Comment: gcc wouldn't get nearly as much entertainment silently laughing at you if it flat out told you what the problem was, would it? Compiler's gotta have some fun.

Comment: @user4581301 Haha, yeah, I love that compiler, but it can be sadistic at times. Maybe I'm just a masochist ;)

Comment: Better than the good ol' days of *syntax error on line 31459* when the program is only 300 lines. Modern compilers *wish* they could be that annoying.

Comment: @user4581301 At least in those days I never expected the compiler to help me much. Now that they're way better, I'm more disappointed in cases when they aren't helpful :p

Comment: With you on that. Learned early to keep a few extra compilers around to throw at a program if I couldn't understand the error message. If Turbo C emitted nonsense maybe Watcom or cl could make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

To start, there is [temp.arg.nontype#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a **converted constant expression** ([expr.const]) of the type of the template-parameter.
>
> [Note 1: If the template-argument is an overload set (or the address of such, including forming a pointer-to-member), the matching function is selected from the set ([over.over]). — end note]

We can then follow that to [expr.const#10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10):

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only ...

From that rule, we can see that the variable `cp` can't possibly be a constant expression since it is not even *potentially-constant* according to [expr.const#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3):

> A variable is potentially-constant if it is constexpr or it has reference or const-qualified integral or enumeration type.

So `cp` is not a valid template-argument for a non-type template parameter, and you get an error.

Note that this is where the apparent inconsistency arises with `ci`. Since `ci` has a const-qualified integral type, it can be used as a template-argument for a non-type template parameter.

Similarly, all the other calls to `f` are allowed as well, since the template-argument in each case is a constant expression:

1. `g` is a function with external linkage, and so its address is a constant expression.
2. `5` is a constant integral expression.
3. `cexprp` and `cexpri` are both `constexpr` variables.

Comment: The limitation for potentially-constant expressions which are not constexpr seems a bit dated. literaltype or such would make more sense since that was introduced.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, that's true. Literal type is used half a dozen times in expr.const. Maybe it should be considered a wording defect? I'm not sure about that though.